# Simulating from some polynomial distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, polynomials, random-variables, simulation

Let $f:\mathcal{R}^+\to \mathcal{R}^+$ a continuous distribution of the type
$$
f(x|a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n)=\frac{1}{k}(a_0+\sum_{i=1} a_i x^i),
$$
where $a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are given parameters and $k$ the normalizing constant, that is
$$
k=\int_0^{\infty} f(x|a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n)dx
$$

My questions is, what is the most efficient way to simulate from this distribution?

My first thought: since this is a polynomial, the c.d.f. is given by the integral $F(x|a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n)=\int_{0}^x f(t|a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n)dt$, which might be computationally fast (?), so we could use the inverse transform sampling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). However, thinking of thousands of values, this might become (time) inefficient.

are there other alternatives? thanks.

Comment: Your variable of integration matches the variable in the upper limit of integration, by the way.

Comment: sorry, I have fixed it. thanks.

Comment: I believe that a distribution with a polynomial density must have bounded support; on the positive real line, I believe all polynomials diverge except for constants.  Did you see section 4.5 of Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation?

Comment: Correct, this is implicit, since the constant k exists. How could we simulate from it? cheers

Comment: Are the values $a_0, a_1, ...$ all non-negative?  Can you give an example of these parameters?